# Date Vs. Time bar graph in Ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, geom-bar

I'm new to RShiny and trying to plot a count against date graph on R (The data set consists of patients visited to a hospital). Below is the code I used.

```
timeCounts <- data.frame(table(mydata[,1])) #the date column
colnames(timeCounts) <- c("pDate", "pCount")
ggplot(timeCounts, aes(x=pDate, y= pCount, fill=pDate)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

This generates an unexpected graph which looks like this:
[plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LCFH.png) But my intention was to get either a line graph connecting values or a bar graph (height proportionate to count per day) Could you please help me fix this?

After converting pDate into Date format, below graph was generated: [plot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucGK3.png)

Sample data looks like this: [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMiys.png)

What I want to generate is a graph of this:

```
pDate     pCount
1/1/2020    36
1/10/2020   60
1/12/2020   63
1/13/2020   59
1/14/2020   80
```

Comment: Your `pDate` is not of type `Date`. Instead, it is all strings, which means according to R and `ggplot2`, it is categorical. Use `timeCounts$pDate <- as.Date(timeCounts$pDate, format="%d/%m/%Y")` and try again.

Comment: I think r2evans has a typo, use `format = "%m/%d%Y"`. But that should take care of it.

Comment: Thank you r2evans and Gregor Thomas. But now I get this plot (added above in the question) with pDate as the legend and x-axis upto 2021-01. How can I solve this?

Comment: Why do you need to use `fill=pDate`? That seems unnecessary. And please provide a minimal working example next time.

Comment: For daily counts, you may want a `geom_line` type graph. If you prefer `geom_bar`, then you may want to group the counts into weeks or months. Difficult to know which one is better without the data.

Comment: @Edward I changed it to pCount and tried and got the same graph. Sure will try that. And will post data as well. Now running into a different issue with as.Date function generating NAs

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to create a barplot or a line plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

timeCounts %>%
  mutate(pDate = as.Date(pDate, format="%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=pDate, y=pCount)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")

timeCounts %>%
  mutate(pDate = as.Date(pDate, format="%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=pDate, y=pCount)) + 
  geom_line()
```

**Data**:

```
timeCounts <- structure(list(pDate = c("1/1/2020", "1/10/2020", "1/12/2020", 
"1/13/2020", "1/14/2020"), pCount = c(36L, 60L, 63L, 59L, 80L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thank you @Edward :)